# Getting the default RTL codepage in Lazarus

Tags: utf-8, lazarus, freepascal

Lazarus [Wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unicode_Support_in_Lazarus) states

> Lazarus (actually its LazUtils package) takes advantage of that API
>   and changes it to UTF-8 (CP_UTF8). It means also Windows users now use
>   UTF-8 strings in the RTL

In our cross-platform and cross-compiler code, we'd like to detect this specific situation. GetACP() Windows API function still returns "1252", and so does GetDefaultTextEncoding() function in Lazarus. But the text (specifically, the filename returned by FindFirst() function) contains the string with UTF8-encoded filename, and the codepage of the string (variable) is 65001 too.

So, how do we figure out that the RTL operates with UTF8 strings by default? I've spent several hours trying to figure this out from Lazarus source code, but probably I am missing something ...

I understand that in many scenarios, we need to inspect the codepage of each specific string, but I am interested in the way to find out the default RTL codepage which is UTF8 in Lazarus, yet Windows-defined one in FPC/Windows without Lazarus.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, that there's no single code page variable or function. Results of the filesystem API calls are converted to the codepage, defined in DefaultRTLFileSystemCodePage variable. The only problem is that this variable is present in the source code and is supposed to be in system unit, but the compiler doesn't see it.

Comment: They should be there. But FPC 3.0.x+

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Yes, I also thought so, but for whatever reason, the compiler doesn't resolve them. FPC 3.0.2 is the only version that I have on the development system (and if it were not 3.0+, I wouldn't get UTF8 as default in the first place).

Comment: Here it works with stock installed FPC 3.0.2/win32 with just a "begin writeln(defaultsystemcodepage)'; end." program